# Testing uploaded file in zf2

Tags: file, post, controller, zend-framework2, phpunit

I want to test a action inside a zf2 controller that takes a file and process it. I tried the following code for reacting on post data:

```
public function testIndexActionCanBeAccessed()
{
    $this->dispatch('/', 'POST', array('test_file' => 'abcdefgh'));
    $this->assertResponseStatusCode(200);
}
```

The problem ist that the 'test_file' paramater is handled as post parameter. So my question is, how can i achieve that php/zf2 handles the parameter as a file and not as a post paramater?

I tried to find an answer in the zf2 documentation and in the file 'Zend\Test\PHPUnit\Controller\AbstractHttpControllerTestCase' without success.

Comment: http://pierrerambaud.com/blog/php/2012-12-29-testing-upload-file-with-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok thanks to the link Sam provided i can now test uploaded files, so here is the working code using the simple global variable **`$_FILES`**:

```
public function testIndexActionCanBeAccessed()
{
    $_FILES['userfile']['name'] = 'testName';
    $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] = 'path/to/fixture';

    $this->dispatch('/', 'POST');
    $this->assertResponseStatusCode(200);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
// within some AbstractHttpControllerTestCase test method
$upload = new \Zend\Stdlib\Parameters([
    'upload' => [
        'name' => 'blah.blah',
        'type' => 'blah',
        'tmp_name' => '/tmp/blah',
        'error' => 0
    ]
]);
$this->getRequest()->setFiles($upload);
$this->dispatch('/url', 'POST');
```

Then in controller:

```
/**
 * Be strict on where you get file info! No blind unions.
 */
$data = $request->getPost()->toArray();
$data['upload'] = current($request->getFiles()->toArray());
```